# Assetic dump generate empty files

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I have done `assets:install --symlink` and `assetic:dump`. But it generates empty files for both css and js. See image below.

[image: CSS Dumping]

I have tried to upgrade symfony into version 2.8. But it still doesn't work. My project is in Windows 7.

This is my config

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: true
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less:
            node: %node_path%
            node_paths: [%node_modules_path%]
            apply_to: "\.less$"
        uglifyjs2:
            bin: %kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs
            mangle: true
        uglifycss:
            bin: %kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/.bin/uglifycss
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
        yui_js:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
    bundles: [BossAgencyAppBundle, BossAgencyPolicyBundle, BossAgencyReportBundle]
```

Here is the location of node

```
node_path: 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node'
node_modules_path: 'C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules'
```